# unformat string number with thousand comma golang

Tags: go

I have this string "1,090"

I want to convert it to float

```
v := "1,090"
s, err := strconv.ParseFloat(v, 32)
if  err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("err: %s\n", err)
    return
}
fmt.Printf("%T, %v\n", s, s)
```

But it returns an error:

```
//err: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "1,090": invalid syntax
```

So anybody know to convert it to float?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it is failed because `"1,090"` has `,` comma in it. You have to remove the `,` from the string before you use `strconv.ParseFloat(v, 32)`. One way to remove comma is by using [strings.Replace()](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace):

```
v := "1,090"

v = strings.Replace(v, ",", "", -1)

s, err := strconv.ParseFloat(v, 32)
if  err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err: %s\n", err)
        return
}
fmt.Printf("%T, %v\n", s, s)
```

Comment: I knew of this command before and didn't think about it, thanks !